# UITableViewCell displays differently in App than in Interface builder

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Here is how the tableViewCell appears within the TableVIew in the storyboard. The Cell is a custom made cell in the interface builder.

[image: TableViewCell as it appears in storyboard]

Here is how the same TableView appears live.

[image]

Im wondering what is causing the lives Cell white background to be truncated and turned grey. I would like the entire Cell to look the same as it does in the Storyboard.

Comment: Check once without autolayout

Comment: Fixed it! The problem is that TableView row Height is set to the default value of 44. The custom tableViewCell is set to a height of 120. Auto-layout will set the tableViewCell height automatically, this is not true though for the tableVIew itself.